# How to represent a quantile function graphically and represent its median on the graphic/plot?

Tags: r

So I have this function:

```
y=-2*log(1-x);
```

The exercise says I have to **represent this function in a plot** and then **calculate** its **median** **and represent/identify it on the plot**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `x` is all values between 0 and 1, and `y` = (-2)log<sub>10</sub>(1-x), here is what you can do:

```r
# evenly sample a bunch of points between 0 and 1
x = seq(0, 1, 0.0001)

y = -2*log10(1-x)

# calculate the median of y
Y = median(y) 
Y
#[1] 0.60206

# when x supposed to be all values between 0 and 1, 
# x is at half way between 0 and 1 when y is at median 
X = 0.5
#X = 1-10^(-Y/2) # algebraically, this works, too
#X
##[1] 0.5

# plot x and y, and identify the point of (X,Y)
library(ggplot2)

qplot(x,y, geom="line") + geom_point(aes(X,Y), col = "blue", size = 4)
```

[image: ggplot method]

The big blue dot on the plot is at the median.

**Alternative approach with the base `plot()` function**

```r
y <- function(x) {-2*log10(1-x)}

Y  = y(0.5) # y median
Y
#[1] 0.60206

plot(y, 0, 1, ylab="y", xlab="x", lwd=2)
points(0.5, Y)
```

[image: plot method]

The open circle in the plot indicates the median.

Comment: Thanks for the help, and sry to bother you but I set the wrong function it is : "-2*log(1-x)" instead of "2*log(1-x)",, I want something like you did but the x is all values between 0 and 1. I want something like this: https://imgur.com/E5gKgjm with the blue dot in it representing the median.

Comment: I can change this to give you the answer--all I need to do is tweak my `x` and `y` and redo my algebra--but this is your homework assignment. I've shown you the how-to. See if you can figure it out first with this solution.

Comment: I tried to set the X value as it is below. But when I calculate the median of Y it should give me around ~0.6 and instead it returns ~1.36. And the blue isn't quite in the right spot.

Comment: I've already to do like this: 
y <- function(x) {-2*log(1-x)}
plot(y, 0, 1, ylab="y", xlab="x", lwd=2)                  But how do I represent the value of x=0.5 ?

Comment: Do not take that image in imgur.com/E5gKgjm as the correct answer. It's x is not restricted between 0 and 1.

Comment: Your plot() is a good simple approach. To add an extra point to the plot, use `points(x,y)` right after `plot(...)`, where x and y are your coordinates.

Comment: My mistake I am sorry but I'll try to explain my point again: I want a graphic like this one: https://imgur.com/T1AXx32. I want this function: -2*log(1-x) but I want to calculate the median and represent it on the plot where x=[0,1] so when x is 0,5.

Comment: OOHH, I know what's wrong, the "log(1-x)" in your equation uses log base 10. `log()` in R uses the natural log, or "ln()". So we just got to change `log()` to `log10()`.

Comment: OMG that it !! But still the dot isn't in the right place now, but at least the function graph/plot is right now ! Now it's only the dot left. I tried to invert the Capital X with the capital Y but the dot isn't right neither is the median result wich should be as I said before around 0.6...

Comment: Never mind I made it work, thanks for all the effort helping me man !!

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're trying to do?

```
library(tidyverse)
data.frame(x = rnorm(n = 50, mean = 0.5, sd = 0.2)) %>%
  mutate(y = (-2 * log(1 - x))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_smooth(col = "black", se = FALSE) +
  geom_point(aes(x = median(x), y = median(y)),
             col = "blue", size = 4) +
  expand_limits(x = c(0,1))
```

[image: example.png]

Comment: Yes but the value of Y should be around 0.6, and thanks for the answer .

Comment: `rnorm(n = 50, mean = 0.5, sd = 0.2)` selects 50 numbers from a normal distribution with a mean of 0.5 - the median may therefore be higher or lower than 0.5, depending on which numbers are chosen. If you take fewer points (e.g. n=20) you will have a greater chance of the median being further from 0.5.

Comment: thanks for the answer again.. I am looking for a plot like this: https://imgur.com/E5gKgjm. and the median for this is around 0.6